# /dev/stdout, /dev/stderr cat redirection (unexpected behavior)

Tags: macos, unix, zsh

I did some test with cat and redirection and there are some behaviors I do not understand.
I understand that when you cat `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/stderr`, it tells cat to read from terminal(like cat without arguments).
But why when I do

```
cat /dev/stdout > file.txt
```

I got a permission denied: `cat: /dev/stdout: Permission denied` (for me it should behave like `cat /dev/stdout` with no redirections and output to the file.txt) but when I do:

```
cat /dev/stderr > file.txt
```

what is written goes well to file.txt, it must not no ? And also
why

```
cat /dev/stderr 2> file.txt
```

does nothing ? But

```
cat /dev/stderr 2>&2 > file.txt
```

redirect well to file.txt.

I just wanna know why it behave like that in those cases.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its an order of operations effect.

The shell redirections happen in the shell as it is setting up the environment to exec the command.  `/dev/stdout` however is just a filename (string) that is passed as an argument to to command and not processed by the shell at all.

So when you run `cat /dev/stdout > file.txt` the shell first opens file.txt for writing, then changes stdout to refer to that file descriptor, then runs the `cat` program with `/dev/stdout` as an argument.
The `cat` program then tries to open `/dev/stdout` for reading.

Now `/dev/stdout` isn't a real file -- its generally just a symlink to `/dev/fd/1`, which is either a device special file, or something on custom dev filesystem, so opening involves calling a special routine in the device driver which tries to dup the stdout filedescriptor as a new file descriptor with read privledges.  The problem is that stdout is a file descriptor referring to file.txt with write privedges, but no read privledges, so you get a "Permission Denied".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i understand better why it behave like this in my first and second example.
But do you have an idea why `cat /dev/stderr 2> file.txt` behave differently than `cat /dev/stderr 2&>2 file.txt` ?.
I know that the operator `&>` say that what is next is a file descriptor not a file.
So for me it should behave exactly the same, i'm just redirecting to the same file descriptor but it behave differently.

Comment: Assuming you mean `2>&2`, that redirects file descriptor 2 to file descrptor 2 (ie, noop), so this is the same as `cat /dev/stderr file.txt` -- reads from the terminal followed by reading from `file.txt`.  `2&>2` is not a redirect at all, so would run `cat /dev/stderr 2` in the background, then try to run `file.txt` with stdout redirected to a file called `2`

Comment: That's right, thanks, it's clearer. I wanted to say `2>&2`(`>&` operator) in my first comment, not `2&>2`,  (it was a typing error).